# Difference when using backticks in double quotes and single quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, bash-scripting

Why to the following two executions differ in output? (I need double quotes for variables in my eventual command)

```
$ sudo su -c "echo `cat /root/root_file`"
cat: /root/root_file: Permission denied
$ sudo su -c 'echo `cat /root/root_file`'
Yay, highly classified content!
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bash performs [a series of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) *before* the command is executed (`sudo` in this case). In the first case, the command substitution is performed because it's in double quotes -- it executes as you, hence the error. In the second case, the single quotes prevent expansions, so the backticks are not substituted until root's shell is running.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Answer (score 5):

In the first example the backticks are evaluated by your shell (as you and not root). Try with

```
sudo su -c "echo `whoami`"
```

In the second one with the single quotes `'` the whole string `` echo `cat /root/root_file` `` is passed to the root shell.